# Como agregar una columna de tipo de dato blob con un valor por defecto vacio en hana

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sap, hana

Estoy intentando agregar una columna a una tabla de Hana sql de tipo de dato blob, pero mi tabla ya contiene datos y no debe ser not null, lo que hace que no me deje agregar la columna. alguien sabe la estructura correcta.

yo lo estoy haciendo asi:

```
ALTER TABLE "CLIENTES"."DATOS" ADD ("IMAGEN" BLOB NOT NULL DEFAULT)
```

es el que me marca error, alguien podria ayudarme

Comment: Cuál es el error que te marca?

Comment: Could not execute 'ALTER TABLE "CLIENTES"."DATOS" ADD ("IMAGEN" BLOB NOT NULL DEFAULT)'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near ")": line 1 col 59 (at pos 67)

Comment: Parece que sobran etiquetas, algunas no se relacionan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto sucede porqué la tabla ya tiene filas. Existen dos caminos.

1. Verificar si puedes usar `ALTER TABLE "CLIENTES"."DATOS" ADD ("IMAGEN" BLOB NOT NULL NOVALIDATE )`
2. Si no lo logras entonces lo correcto sería primero alterar la tabla así `ALTER TABLE "CLIENTES"."DATOS" ADD ("IMAGEN" BLOB)`, luego asignar un valor para  los datos que ya tiene la tabla, para ello usas la función UPDATE con un SET en la columna IMAGEN, una vez que ya todos los campos  tengan un valor diferente de NULL, agrega de nuevo la restricción de  not null para esta columna usando  `ALTER TABLE | ALTER COLUMN` y agrega la restricción.

Answer (score 0):

Inicializa con un BLOB vacío:

```
ALTER TABLE "CLIENTES"."DATOS" 
  ADD ("IMAGEN" BLOB NOT NULL DEFAULT EMPTY_BLOB())
```